# Google Maps geocode service is not working(google blocking our request)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

We are using Google Maps geocode service to get Latitude and Longitude for a given address,
We invoke google maps geocode service in a loop for each address(the loop max size is 50 addresses).
we are using this MAPs for State of Texas HHSC Help website (https://www.211texas.org/211/)

Below is service URL that we are using to get Latitude and Longitude.

**http://maps.google.com/maps/geo**?q=1601%20Rutherford%20Ln,Austin%20TX%2078754&key=ABQIAAAAU6mRnxlKP7D0V5v9DF3PIRT7KmOOtdkA0SYMLaxMRemphasized textpf2Wu2TCRTCqatXcIx0ULuVNHCz_jELYoAgXw&output=csv&oe=utf8&sensor=false

Google thinks this is Unusual traffic from our computer network, **but it is not**.

If you copy and paste the above link on your browser URL, you will see the below message.

The service is not working and it says 
We're sorry...
... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
See Google Help for more information.

Need help , 
Sorry,If this is not right place to post this issue,
How to contact google on this issue, since its not commercial website issue. 
or is there any alternative way to get Latitude and Longitude for given address.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your code comply with the quota and rate limit on the Geocoder?  Are you checking status on the geocode requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the documented endpoint.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) specifies:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, do I need to re-generate the API Console Key? When I tried with existing Maps API Key , I got the below response.   <GeocodeResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
<error_message>The provided API key is invalid.</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>

Comment: Yup.  v2 API keys won't work. Go to the API Console and get a new one enabled for that API.

Comment: This is working without API Console Key, is that legal to use?

Comment: I believe so. But if you run into the quota you may want to use a key; that also allows you to track usage with the API console and purchase additional quota (haven't done that myself)

Comment: I see the usage limits of GeoCode service,  Rate limit of 10 requests per second. how do we handle this?, In our scenario there may be more than 10 request per second. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I post a another question on this forum, is there a way to pass all our address as an array and get the response back as array?